# How to check which package depends on ros-kinetic-librealsense2

Tags: ros, rosdep, ros-kinetic, realsense

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I stumbled upon an annoying problem. I'm building quite big docker image containing robot's workspace. Docker build process fails on step where I'm trying to resolve and install missing dependencies using `rosdep`. Looks like one of the packages depends on `ros-kinetic-librealsense2` package which simply does not exists and kills my building process.
I'm getting:

```
apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-kinetic-librealsense2] failed
 
apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [ros-kinetic-librealsense2]
```

How to locate that problematic package? I tried

```
rosdep which-depends
```

but it returns nothing.

Thx!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327472/how-to-check-which-package-depends-on-ros-kinetic-librealsense2/) by [fitter](https://answers.ros.org/users/33900/fitter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2019-07-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-07-03**:
Using grep to search your code base for any occurrence of the string `librealsense2` would probably a good way to start.

```
grep "librealsense2" . -r
```

From the root of your code base will show you a list of files which contain that string.

**Comment by [fitter](https://answers.ros.org/users/33900/fitter/) on 2019-07-03**:
Thx, I did that, but in fact I checked for "ros-kinetic-librealsense2". I didn't knew that dependencies are defined without "ros-kinetic" prefix, so I received nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some searching I found this discussion:
https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros/issues/808

Looks like the librealsense2 got deleted from ROS repositories, but for some reason realsense package still depends on it, which blocks `rosdep install`. There is a PR with fix waiting for acceptance.

The workaround for now is to use `rosdep install` with `-r` flag, and, if you are using docker, end the RUN command which spawns `rosdep install` with `; exit 0` to continue after rosdep returns 1.

Just remember its not a proper solution and it should be reverted after realsense PR got merged or librealsense2 lib comes back to repository.

Hope it's going to help someone with similar problem

---

Originally posted by [fitter](https://answers.ros.org/users/33900/fitter/) with karma: 56 on 2019-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2